# Virtual Device booting with black screen; not running code; goldfish-pipe

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I have set up a virtual device to run my app on android studio. The virtual device screen remains black on running of the code. I get several error messages:

Emulator: C:\MY PATH\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(184, 73), size=(560x21), dirty=(560x130 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))

I have deleted and set up several virtual devices but the error persists.

I have set up several virtual devices.

Emulator: C:\MY PATH\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(184, 73), size=(560x21), dirty=(560x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))

Black screen with error message: RESETTING FOR COLD BOOT

Comment: Try to choose *Cold boot* in an emulator's configuration. **Virtual Device Configuration -> Show Advanced Settings**.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the original error. Although, I am now having issues with the emulator taking too long to boot, when I want to test my apps. This boot time is so slow, that the build fails. The error now is that my ABD is obsolete with performance issues. Any fixes?